# How do I set a delay in HTML A-Frame

Tags: html, animation, aframe

I am studying A-Frame and can't find any tutorials that show how to set a delay between animations. How would I do this with as few lines of code as possible?

Code:

```
<a-box color=¨#fffff¨position="-5 0 -10" width="2.5" height="1.7" depth="1.7"> 
    <a-animation attribute="position" from="-5 0 -10" to="-14 -0.8 -10" dur="6000">
    </a-animation> 
    <a-animation attribute="rotation" from="0 0 0" to="0 0 10" dur="6000"> 
    </a-animation> 
</a-box>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Show us what you have tried first.

Comment: I need a three second delay between two animation on the same object.

Comment: Can you please add the code that you have tried yourself?

Comment: Sorry it wont let me format the code how it should be but I think it should still be fine.

Comment: Yay like I said I need a 3 second delay between those two animations.

Comment: I tried <a-delay dur=¨3000¨><a/-delay>

Comment: That was just the most intuitive way of doing it but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-animation-timeline-component

Or write a component that triggers the first animation, waits, then triggers second.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('trigger', {
  init: function () {
    this.el.emit('triggerfirst');
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.el.emit('triggersecond');
    }, 300);
  }
});

<a-entity animation__1="startEvents: triggerfirst" animation__2="startEvents: triggersecond" trigger>
```

You can have `trigger` component wait on an event too if you want.